# Preventing duplicate blockchain attack

Tags: blockchain

Hoping someone can help me answer a question regarding a potential attack that could occur with a blockchain.

Suppose Alice is trying to attack Bob by sending him false blockchains. In this scenario, suppose Alice wants to repeatedly send a blockchain that records that Bob owes Alice $10, and she has successfully found a proof of work that creates an appropriate hash.

What is there to stop Alice from taking this block, and broadcasting it repeatedly to Bob so that on his side, he sees a growing blockchain, each with a record that he owes Alice?

From what I understand, the way that the "true" blockchain is determined is by a matter of size. So as long as Alice broadcasts her fake block to Bob quickly enough, wouldn't her records appear to be the correct blockchain that Bob would then need to accept?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? Is the question too vague or incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, this isn't the stack site for this. Not that we don't do theoretical questions, it's just that this is completely hypothetical with no actual code involved. It's better you check out [bitcoin stack site](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the strength of a blockchain network is the number of peers. Alice wouldn't just have to convince Bob her bogus chain is legit, but 51% of the total network, a network which is actively building a blockchain that contradicts hers.

Also, keep in mind that transactions are typically cryptographically signed. In order to have a valid block hash that says Bob owes Alice $10, Bob would need to sign a transaction to that effect.